# Creating UML class diagrams in VS from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, architecture, uml

I am designing a simple class library and have already coded some parts of the interfaces/classes.

I would like to use the existing code pieces to display them in the UML diagram.

I could not find a way to do this. I am running Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

What are the alternatives to this? creating all classes/interfaces in the diagram from scratch?

What's the point of having the diagram "detached" from the real project?

Comment: Have you tried the class wizard in VS10?

Comment: What is the class wizard? never came across this...

Comment: You can right click your project and choose "view class diagram" option in it.. I think the links below in this thread talk pretty much about it ...

Answer (score 2):

Add a class diagram to your solution. Drag and drop files from Solution Explorer or classes from Class Explorer onto the diagram.

From there, you can "grow" the diagram by right-clicking on types and choosing to "Show Base Class" or "Show Derived Classes". Or right-click on properties and fields and choose "Show as Association" or "Show as Collection Association".

Comment: Class diagram doesn't show interaction between classes (inheirts/implements/etc)

Answer (score 2):

VS, atleast the version I use, does not have very robust UML support. They do however offer a pretty nifty "class diagram" feature. Maybe that is what you are referring to. You can easily create a class diagram from existing code in one of two ways.

1. To create a class diagram for an entire project, right click on the project name in the Solution Explorer and click "View Class Diagram"
2. To create a class diagram for just some classes, add a new item of type class diagram to your project. You can then drag and drop files from the Solution Explorer onto the class diagram canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new item of type ClassDiagram to your project, and then just drag and drop your existing classes there